# Twig conditional shorthand fails

Tags: twig, conditional-statements, shorthand

I try to use shorthand twig conditional but fails to parse the expected

```
<a href="{{ primaryNav.getLinkHref }}"  {% primaryNav.getModalOptions ? "data-toggle="modal" data-target="'.primaryNav.getModalOptions."': ''%} target="{{ primaryNav.getLinkTarget }}">
```

but I get

```
Unexpected character "'"
```

How to use this shorthand in the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twig concatenate operator is **`~`** not `.`. Additionally you have mess with single and double quote. The ternary operator must be used between `{{ .. }}` not `{% .. %}`. Moreover `{{ foo ? 'yes' }}` is the same as `{{ foo ? 'yes' : '' }}`. Try this:

```
<a href="{{ primaryNav.getLinkHref }}" {{ primaryNav.getModalOptions ? 'data-toggle="modal" data-target="' ~ primaryNav.getModalOptions ~ '"'}} target="{{ primaryNav.getLinkTarget }}">
```

More info in [doc](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators).